# macOS sierra scrollbar issue

Tags: macos

After upgrading to macOS sierra I've noticed that scrollbars are appearing always, even if I go to settings and then select `appear when scrolling` it still shows them and after quitting and going back to settings it reverts back to `appear always`. Is there any ways to solve this issue myself?

Comment: It's beta software. It's probably a bug. We (generally) don't support beta software.

Comment: As JMY1000 said, it must be a beta bug. I recommend to you report a bug with “Feedback Assistant” app, which is located in the /Applications/Utilities folder, in order to help Apple to fix it.

Comment: @JMY1000 Yeah seems like that

Comment: Related: ['Show scroll bars' stuck on Always](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245994/show-scroll-bars-stuck-on-always)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to finder and press command+shift+G on your keyboard and the dialogue box that appears paste in - this path in it

/Users/your
username/Library/Preferences/com.apple.AppleMultitouchMouse.plist and delete this plist file com.apple.AppleMultitouchMouse.plist then go to system preferences and click on general and instead of selecting appear when scrolling select automatically based on mouse or trackpad

Answer (score 1):

Go to "System Settings > General" and set "Show scroll bars" to "(o) When scrolling".

In my case, this setting was set to "(o) Automatically ..." after update and the scroll bars have been visible all the time.

Comment: Thanks, But I already did that as I said it didn't work, every time I change it goes back to appear always.